# 3 tabs with each listview populated via database in a single activity? Can it slow down the phone?

Tags: android, listview, tabs, tabactivity

i was planning to that way, i dont know how to use tab activity or fragments, and im in kinda rush now. Is this way of building the class may slow down the phone? each listview will probably have 30 entries each. Thanks

developing with platform 2.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on the content that's to be displayed. 90 list items (not visible at the same time) of only text aren't heavy at all, while 90 list items full of images would be significantly heavier.

Comment: i also want to have an alertdialog and button slider with the same activity. And another tab (textviews) that will display database data gathered from different tables... though all is text.. i really need to know, bec if after I built it, and have some "Not Responding", it would suck

Comment: Well, try to keep the "heavy" operations (database, network and such) off the GUI thread, and you won't be seeing any `ANR`'s. For example, use a `CursorLoader` for the database. :-)

Comment: Obviously, the more elements you display on the screen, the more the device has to work - however, you should be fine as long as you do the heavy-lifting (as said above) off the GUI thread.

Comment: No problems, good luck with your app. As a bonus, here's a link to the official docs regarding performance --> http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html :)